# How to define a route and then create a simple crosslink to that route?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

This API is clear enough...

```
<Button
      title="Go to Details"
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
    />
```

But how do I register this "Details" route for a component?  In the React Navigation docs, it is often suggested to do something like...

```
export default StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
});
```

However, the above code does not just register a route, it also affects how the UI is presented.  I don't want these coupled.  I don't want the way in which I register/define routes to have any immediate effect on the GUI.

There must be a way to simply register a route so that when I call navigation.navigate('SomeRoute'), the relevant screen will load.

Even the documentation for [building a custom router](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-routers.html) seems to assume that I want to render something, rather than just define routes.  But I just want to register a route so I can call navigation.navigate('Someroute').

Comment: I think it might have something to do with routeConfigs, but I haven't been able to find where routeConfigs is defined yet.

Comment: I think the answer might be to create a custom navigator.  This looks like what I need to do: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the route „Details“ with your desired Screen to the stacknavigator. Exactly like with Home. If you navigate to another route the UI changes to another view thats the whole point of routing with screens with react-navigation.

Comment: I don't want to use StackNavigator.  StackNavigator does more than define routes.  It also affects the GUI of the app.

Comment: But in your answer you are telling us : „There must be a way to simply register a route so that when I call navigation.navigate('SomeRoute'), the relevant screen will load.“ Thats EXACTLY what the Stacknavigator does. When you call „navigation.navigate(„SomeRoute“) the screen attached to that route will appear. Are you sure you are not mixin up concepts?

Comment: The StackNavigator has other effects on the UI besides just appearing the screen.  It does more than what I want, in this case.  But I see now that navigators are in a way just renderers, so I should be good if I make a custom navigator.  This sentence in the docs made a light go on: “The navigators render application screens which are just React components.”

Comment: Cristian's answer is essentially correct.  I initially resisted the idea that the code should handle both routing and navigation in a way that is (at least from my perspective) somewhat coupled.  But there is no fighting it.  It's clear now that the best way is to use React Navigation and, because I'm new to React, I should not try to combine React Navigation with other navigation libraries, and should not try to write something myself.  Once I went to a pure React Navigation approach and dropped my other navigation library, things got much easier.